# Allow only to purchase a product once per customer in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I have a Woocommerce shop selling virtual products. How can I disable users from buying the same product again? If the user bought the product already then he/she shouldn't be able to add this product to the cart.

Comment: This isn't a code question, so I'm not posting this as an answer. On a product editing page, in the Inventory section check the box marked "Sold Individually"

Comment: The "Sold Individually" under Inventory section is only for the current cart session. We want only to allow to purchase a product once per customer. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a functions in your child theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'products_purchasable_once', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'products_purchasable_once', 10, 2 );
function products_purchasable_once( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // Here set the product IDs in the array that can be purchased only once 
    $targeted_products = array(**ADD YOUR PRODUCT IDS HERE**);

    // Only for logged in users and not for variable products
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() || $product->is_type('variable') )
        return $purchasable; // Exit

    $user = wp_get_current_user(); // The WP_User Object

    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $targeted_products ) &&
    wc_customer_bought_product( $user->user_email, $user->ID, $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
```

add your product ids in this section ADD YOUR PRODUCT IDS HERE i have marked in code

***UPDATE BELOW**

```
function disable_repeat_purchase( $purchasable, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        return $purchasable;
    }

    // Get the ID for the current product
    $product_id = $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->variation_id : $product->id; 

    // return false statement if the customer has bought the product / variation
    if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product_id ) ) {
        $purchasable = false;
    }

    // Double-check for variations: if parent is not purchasable, then variation is not
    if ( $purchasable && $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $purchasable = $product->parent->is_purchasable();
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_repeat_purchase', 10, 2 );
```

**Update 2**

```
function purchase_disabled_message() {

    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {

        foreach ( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
            // Render the purchase restricted message if it has been purchased
            if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $variation_id ) ) {
                render_variation_non_purchasable_message( $product, $variation_id );
            }
        }

    } else {
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( wp_get_current_user()->user_email, get_current_user_id(), $product->id ) ) {
            echo '<div class="woocommerce"><div class="woocommerce-info wc-nonpurchasable-message">You\'ve already purchased this product! It can only be purchased once per customer.</div></div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'purchase_disabled_message', 31 );


function render_variation_non_purchasable_message( $product, $no_repeats_id ) {

    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $product->has_child() ) {

        $variation_purchasable = true;

        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {

            if ( $no_repeats_id === $variation['variation_id'] ) {
                $variation_purchasable = false; 
                echo '<div class="woocommerce"><div class="woocommerce-info wc-nonpurchasable-message js-variation-' . sanitize_html_class( $variation['variation_id'] ) . '">You\'ve already purchased this product! It can only be purchased once per customer.</div></div>';
            }
        }
    }

    if ( ! $variation_purchasable ) {
        wc_enqueue_js("
            jQuery('.variations_form')
                .on( 'woocommerce_variation_select_change', function( event ) {
                    jQuery('.wc-nonpurchasable-message').hide();
                })
                .on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
                    jQuery('.wc-nonpurchasable-message').hide();
                    if ( ! variation.is_purchasable ) {
                        jQuery( '.wc-nonpurchasable-message.js-variation-' + variation.variation_id ).show();
                    }
                })
            .find( '.variations select' ).change();
        ");
    }
}
```

Comment: how can it be applied for all products please? without indicating product IDs

Comment: are you allowing other products to be purchased or are you completely locking out all products once customer has purchased one of your products

Comment: it should only allow to purchase a specific product once per user. So if the user already bought the product, he/she shouldn't  be able to add it to the cart

Comment: Updated my answer this is not tested but should do the trick

Comment: thank you. how can the message be integrated to it saying "you have purchased this product" in single product page?

Comment: see update 2 add this after update 1 in your function

Comment: Your update 2 still displays the Add to Cart button. I used your update 1 and added action hook add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'notpurchasable_show_message', 20 ); inside the function of return false

Comment: The message will be displayed just if the order is "finished". I have bank transfer as a payment method, so the status of the order is manually switched to finished after the user paid. When the order is in "process" the user can buy another product. I don't want this to happen. Is there any way I could make this work?